# Asteroid Oauth loginServiceConfiguration: 'google' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth, ddp

I've followed the 'naive' implementation in the project README: https://github.com/mondora/asteroid-oauth-mixin

The only difference in my code from the example is changing the arrow function to a traditional for the usage of this.

```
asteroid.ddp.on("added", ({collection, id, fields}: { collection: string; fields: {}, id: string }) => {
  if (collection === "meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration") {
    asteroid.loginServiceConfiguration = {
      ...asteroid.loginServiceConfiguration,
      [id]: {
        _id: id,
        ...fields
      }
    };
  }
});
});
asteroid.getServiceConfig = function(providerName: string) { // ts file
  return this.loginServiceConfiguration[providerName];
}
```

When I do asteroid.loginWith('google')

```
index.ts:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'google' of undefined
```

On the meteor backend I also installed `meteor add accounts-base accounts-google` because I assume this is a dependency.

What am I missing? Thanks!

---

I've tried adding  `DDP.loginServiceConfiguration = {}` before the snippet above which resolves the error but creates a new error.

```
asteroid-oauth-mixin.js:787 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined
    at getOauthClientId (asteroid-oauth-mixin.js:787)
    at Object.getOptions (asteroid-oauth-mixin.js:720)
    at Asteroid.loginWith (asteroid-oauth-mixin.js:104)
    at LoginForm../src/routes/accounts/auth/LoginForm.tsx.LoginForm.handleLoginWithGoogle (
```

---

Also when I run `meteor mongo` should `db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.find().count()` be 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to `meteor add service-configuration` and setup my configure-accounts.js and create a google clientId for the application.

This gets me to the point where I have a popup and can choose which user to auth with. Then I receive a new error about target origin mismatch, but I'm going to close this question as resolved.